# Text of full \textwidth inside nested minipage

Tags: minipage, textwidth

Within nested `minipage`s, I would like to place text that occupies the full `\textwidth` of the document indpendent of the current `\linewidth`. The obvious solution of using a `minipage` of width `\textwidth` (prior to the first `minipage`) *seems* to work fine (except for the `Overfull hbox` message).

As desired, minipage **C** take up the full `\textwidth` nested within minipages **A** and **B**:

[image]

#### Questions

1. Are there some issues with this approach that I am not seeing yet?
2. What is the best way to handle the "Overfull hbox"? I could turn them off with `hfuzz=10000`, but wouldn't that suppress the reportting of all such messages.
3. Is there a better way to do this?

#### Notes:

1. Moving the text to be after the `minipage` is not an option as that introduces other complications due to the structure I am working with.
2. If you are curious, this if hack to work around `wrapfigure` issues with lists. I use `minipgage`s for the text and the figure. Then, using the solution from [Typeset Only First n Items or Items after n from a List](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579563) I split my lists into two parts, where the second part of the list is typeset after I have vertically passed the figure. I realize this won't wotk very well if an `\item` in the list is long, but that is rarely the case for my particular use case.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{white}

\newcommand*{\LipsumText}{%
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
   Morbi sagittis mi quis dui condimentum ullamcorper sed nec est. 
   Sed eros orci, varius sit amet sem vel, porttitor sodales libero.%
}


\newlength\FullTextWidth
\setlength\FullTextWidth\textwidth

\fboxsep=0pt
\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
    \textbf{A:}
    \LipsumText%
    
    \noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
        \textbf{B:}
        \LipsumText%
        
        \noindent\fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}{\FullTextWidth}\hfuzz=1000pt
            \textbf{C:}
            \LipsumText%
        \end{minipage}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could silence the overfull box warning using `\leavevmode\rlap{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}<your stuff>\end{minipage}}`.

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comment into an answer. If you know that you'll put a box there that is too wide, but are ok with that, you can silence the overfull box warning by telling TeX that box is small enough. This could easily be done using `\rlap` (or if you prefer `\makebox[\linewidth][l]{<stuff>}` instead, which yields the same output in this example, but would also tell TeX that the current line is full).

Code example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{white}

\newcommand*{\LipsumText}{%
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
   Morbi sagittis mi quis dui condimentum ullamcorper sed nec est. 
   Sed eros orci, varius sit amet sem vel, porttitor sodales libero.%
}


\newlength\FullTextWidth
\setlength\FullTextWidth\textwidth

\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
    \textbf{A:}
    \LipsumText%
    
    \noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
        \textbf{B:}
        \LipsumText%
        
        \noindent\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}{\FullTextWidth}
            \textbf{C:}
            \LipsumText%
        \end{minipage}}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}}%
\end{document}
```

(Notes: I've removed the `\hfuzz` setting, and changed the `\fboxsep` to be `-\fboxrule`, this way the rules show the exact outline of the boxes at the outer corner of the rules, and don't increase the box size).

[image]