# Hide specific \item

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I have thousands of math tasks, which sometimes consist of several sub-questions. The subtasks are separated in an `\enumerate` environment with `\item`. I would like to be able to hide individual `\item` with the following macro

```
\long\def\itema#1\itemb{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{Aufgabea}}{\item#1\itemb}{\itemb}}

\long\def\itemb#1\itemc{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{Aufgabeb}}{\item#1\itemc}{\itemc}}

\long\def\itemc#1\end{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{Aufgabec}}{\item#1\end}{\end}}
```

an example code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{Taska}
\setboolean{Taska}{false}
\newboolean{Taskb}
\setboolean{Taskb}{true}
\newboolean{Taskc}
\setboolean{Taskc}{false}

\long\def\itema#1\itemb{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{Taska}}{\item#1\itemb}{\itemb}}

\long\def\itemb#1\itemc{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{Taskb}}{\item#1\itemc}{\itemc}}

\long\def\itemc#1\end{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{Taskc}}{\item#1\end}{\end}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \itema itema 
        \itemb itemb
        \itemc itemc
        
    \end{enumerate}

    
\end{document}
```

my problem is now if a task only consists of two `\item` commands (`\itema` and `\itemb`) it doesn't work. I would have to somehow add to the `\itema, \itemb ..` macros that they can either end with the next `\item` or with `\end` but don't know how. It would be good if the macros stayed in this style.

Comment: given you are not using the standard `\item` anyway why not use `\itema{item a} \itemb{item b}  \itemc{item c}` then it is trivial and you don't need any boolean tests at all just define `\itema` to be `\def\itema#1{\item#1}` or `\def\itema#1{}` depending if you want the itema or not.

Comment: a lot of people will work with it, so it should be possible to use the normal ``\item``. In addition, according to the client, an ``\item`` with ``{}`` should never be used.

Comment: yes but you are not using normal \item you are using specific commands `\itema`, `\itemb` etc. So forcing those new commands to use a syntax that makes them hard to implement seems a strange constraint.

Comment: Also note that obviously with this implementation you can't use verbatim content inside

Comment: @user202729 already noted that, no verbatim content needed. Don't get paied.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle all right, so do you think that it is not possible without ``{}``?

Comment: Is possible (maybe most straight forward way is to use `environ` package to grab the whole argument and do something with it), but you can see it's not easy if you program it in TeX

Comment: it's possible, I suspect I have an an answer on here but it's alot more code and fragile

Comment: ``\newcommand`` is also possible but it must not be like ``\itema{...}``.

Comment: Does [Typeset Only First n Items or Items after n from a List](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579563/4301) help you acive your goal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want. Give a try to package `dbshow` to filter the questions with labels.

[image]

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dbshow}

\dbNewDatabase{math}{labels=clist, ques=tl}
\begin{dbFilters}{math}
  \dbNewConditional{select}{labels}{label-a, label-b}
\end{dbFilters}
\dbNewStyle{base}{math}{
  before-code = {\dbIfEmptyF{\begin{enumerate}}},
  after-code = {\dbIfEmptyF{\end{enumerate}}},
  item-code = {\item\dbuse{ques}},
}
\dbNewStyle[base]{filter}{math}{raw-filter = {!select}}
\NewDocumentCommand \savemath { O{} m } {%
  \begin{dbitem}{math}[labels={#1}, ques=#2]%
  \end{dbitem}%
}

\begin{document}
\savemath[label-a]{Question 1 with label a.}
\savemath[label-b]{Question 2 with label b.}
\savemath[label-c]{Question 3 with label c.}
\savemath[label-b]{Question 4 with label b.}
\savemath[label-d]{Question 5 with label d.}

\section{Original}
\dbshow{base}{math}
\section{Hide question with label a and b}
\dbshow{filter}{math}
\end{document}
```